# После вставки элемента получаю object Object

Tags: html, jquery

```
 btn=$(".bx-composite-btn")//выбрал кнопку 
    $(".footer li:last-child").after('<li>'+btn+'</li>')//вставил кнопку
    //получил
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>[object Object]</li>//получаю
   <li><a class="bx-composite-btn">текст</a></li>//а должно быть
```

Comment: это все потому, что `btn` это объект, а не строка, и при приведении к строке получается `"[object Object]"`

Comment: @Grundy как исправить?

Comment: очевидно - не вставлять объект, а вставлять строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это все потому, что `btn` это объект, а не строка, и при приведении к строке получается `"[object Object]"`

Для решения можно воспользоваться возможностью создания объектов, а не собирания строки, для этого нужно поменять код вставки

```
btn=$(".bx-composite-btn")//выбрал кнопку 
$(".footer li:last-child").after($('<li>').append(btn))//вставил кнопку
```

В этом случае кнопка перенесется в последний `li`